# How to make a LazyVStack adapt it's column number?

Tags: swiftui

I need SwiftUI to figure out how many columns to use in LazyVStack and adapt it's width according to content.
For that, I decided to use .adaptive grid item, take a look:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let shortNames: [String] = ["Fay", "May", "Chi", "Cal", "Dee", "An", "Rob"]
let longNames: [String] = ["Christofer", "Alexander", "Leopold", "Anastasia", "Jacquelin", "Charlotte"]

var body: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))],
              content: {
                ForEach(longNames, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text("\(name)")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                }
              })
}
```

This is what I get:
[Short names displayed in 4 columns while long names are broken into two lines and 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9pzX.jpg)

So wouldn't it be better for SwiftUI to keep the long text unbreakable and adapt its columns to a more appropriate size and make 3 columns instead of 4?
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtbmK.jpg)

I tried:

```
Text("\(name)")
    .lineLimit(1) // That keeps the text in one line, 
                  // but it gets truncated at the end.
                  // And SwiftUI doesn't expand column width.
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5) // That shrinks the text, 
                             // but doesn't make SwiftUI expand the column width
    .fixedSize() // Still 4 columns
    .padding()
    .background(Color.gray)
```

Comment: Did you try lineLimit(1) and fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) together? That should do it.

Comment: Why does it squeeze the content so hard?
[Example:](https://i.imgur.com/s3518gd.png)

Comment: Hmm. I think there are two issues: One, “adaptive” grids try to make their columns as small as possible. And two, fixedSize views sometimes break their parent’s layout. So your grid columns are all at their minimum size and the Text just overflows the bounds. You need something like UIKit’s “compression resistance priority”, which doesn’t really exits in SwiftUI.

Comment: I think you’ll need to measure your strings, like how folks have built flow layouts in SwiftUI: https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/flow-layout-in-swiftui